# vim - changing the color of selected text

Tags: vim, editor

I am editing a document in vim, it is not code. I am new to vim and come from a Windows background. I am trying to select a block of text and change it's color. I know how to select text using the Visual mode. Can you please tell me how to change the color for the selection?

I would like to define presets, eg. red, green, blue, yellow etc, and do something like this for selected text - `:set color = red`

Is this possible? Can you please show me how?

Comment: Possible, yes.  Easy, no.  It involves adding a syntax highlighting pattern, which is probably not what you had in mind.

Comment: can your selection cross multiple lines?

Comment: Vim is a __plain text__ editor. To see text with colors, you need to use syntax highlighting (which require adding some recognizable feature to your plain text such as a special keyword or spacing) or using another text editor for formatted file types. In the general tradition though, plain text is used to edit a source file which will then generate a final file with your desired visual effects. There are lots of markup languages to do this, ranging from complete ones (like LaTeX) to practical ones (like Markdown) and even a common HTML.

Comment: If you don't mind using plugins, [vim-quickhl](https://github.com/t9md/vim-quickhl) is the closest I know of. It highlights all matches however, which may or may not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Please check [Highlight_multiple_words](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Highlight_multiple_words).
`<leader>m` to enable mapping then you can select text and highlight it with different color as below. (Limit: it doesn't support column selection.)
[image]

[image]

Answer (score -1):

An easy example to highlight the pattern ==> TEXT_TO_HIGHLIGHT.
you could also specify regex in the pattern.

hi CustomGreen ctermbg=35 guibg=black guifg=black
call matchadd('CustomGreen', 'TEXT_TO_HIGHLIGHT')